# TSQL: use CASE in the WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, t-sql

Is there an efficient way of writing this **c#** codes in **t-sql**?

```
string sqlText = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 "
               + "FROM table "
               + "WHERE col1 = @val1 ";

if(condition) // i.e. if type == 'salary'
{
  sqlText += " AND col2 = @val2";
}

sqlText += " ORDER BY col1";
```

What I've done and it's kind of working is to just wap the whole statement by a `if/being/end`.

```
IF(@empType = 'salary')
  BEGIN
     //query statement here...
  END
 ELSE 
  BEGIN
   //same query statement here with the extra logic that C# code adds...
  END
```

The query was used to display data on HTML page. Now, it's been decided to convert the page to SSRS report.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Where is empType  in the database?

Comment: I think this is what you mean: `select col1, col2, col3 from table 
    where col1 = @val1 
    and (@empType is null or (@empType == 'salary' and col2 = @valw))
    orderby col1`

Comment: Why no just handle it with logic? `Where col1 = @val1 AND (@empType <> 'salary' OR col2 = @val2)`

Comment: Wait do you want the `col2 = @val2` check when `@empType` is "salary", or when it isn't "salary"?  The C# code comment implies the former while your SQL comments imply the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table 
WHERE col1 = @val1
  AND (@empType <> 'salary' 
     OR (@empType = 'salary' AND col2 = @val2))
ORDER BY col1
```

but I'm not sure what empType is, if it is a param or something else.

Dynamically building SQL is bad for a few reasons (cannot be optimized reliably by SQL server, more exposure to potential SqlInjection), but a pattern of competing conditions like the above would work.

Consider separate stored procs and calling the correct one via code instead of this kind of mess.

Comment: Why do you have that `1=1` in there?  Also it needs to be true when `@empType` is not "salary"

Comment: @empType is a parameter. In the c# code, it's being checked to add more logic in the Where clause

Comment: @juharr - I forgot to remove the placeholder.

Comment: It's correct now, but the `@empType = 'salary'` part is redundant.

Comment: This is a general question that I have simplified. There are more complex situation where more logic are added to the Where clause using C#